# Replace with value '$' does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i tried to replace a string, provided the string regex with a value that has `$` in the end.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what is happening in

Looking into mdn string replace [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), i found it is expected.

But what should one do he want to ignore this.
Means i want the replacing value should get as it is replaced, with 4 `$`s here.

Comment: hint: you can observe in your first attempt itself that $ in output is half the number you have given in pattern

Comment: *what should one do he want to ignore this.* - You cannot, as this is one of the language features.

Comment: From [the reference you linked in the question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), the first pattern itself says -- *$$ Inserts a "$".*

Comment: okay, but how can we develop a JS system, where client inputs a replacing string and also the replacement value in string. Should we teach client to put double $s in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double the dollars in the replacement pattern as `$$` are actually `$`.

```
.replace(/{{one}}/g, '000$$$$$$$$')
```

See [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) help:

> **Pattern        Inserts**
>   `$$`            Inserts a `"$"`.

If a user types `$` in the replacement (that is, in case it is user-defined) you can just double it:

```js
var ptrn = "{{one}}"; // regex pattern from user input
var repl = "000$$$$"; // replacement from user input
var rx = RegExp(ptrn, "g"); // building a dynamic regex
document.write("pp{{one}}pp".replace(rx, repl.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')));
//                                            ^--- doubling $s-----^
```

Comment: okay, but how can we develop a JS system, where client inputs a replacing string and also the replacement value in string. Should we teach client to put double $s in the end?

Comment: hmm.. thats cool, i had that in my mind just a second before.